# fb-like some time get disappeared with fb-share plugin?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk

Here I am working with asp.net web application, I am using 2 facebook plugin in my web page.

1. Facebook like
2. Facebook share

For facebook share :

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="*******"></a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

For facebook like :

```
 <script>    
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>            
<div class="fb-like" data-href="********" data-send="false" 
  data-layout="button_count" data-width="10" 
  data-show-faces="false" style="width:45px; height:20px;"></div>
```

Case 1. above code work fine when I am using single code.

Case 2 : when I am using both some time facebook like plugin disappeared from page.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think that in this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ is clear that the like button is replace the (old) share button.

Comment: Have you tried the fbml Version of the like button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like button and Share button may be used on one page only if you avoid usage of javascript provided with it and use direct link to `share.php` (which I will not provide for reasons outlined bellow).

If you'll use `http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share` it will break either Share or Like buttons, according to order of javascript inclusion, first one will work, second one is in trouble.

Couple of points to take into consideration:

- Share button is **deprecated** please avoid using it!

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and will no longer be supported.
>
> Share button can be easily replaced with usage of [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed) and [JS-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), which provide more control over sharing functionality:
>   `FB.ui({method: 'feed', link: document.location.href});`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the XFBML Version of the like button:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="language" content="de">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=225116190942635";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://www.google.com"></a>
        <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
        </script>

        <!--<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>-->
        <fb:like href="http://www.google.com" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
    </body>
</html>
```